# Generalization of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have just noticed some similarities while studying when some equations have solutions:

1. For ($n\times n$) matrices, the equation $AX = B$ has solutions if and only if $Im(B) \subseteq Im(A)$.
2. For $\mathbb{Z}_m$, for a natural number $m$ the equation $ax \equiv b \pmod{m}$ has solution if and only if $\gcd(a,m)$ divides   $\gcd(b,m)$
3. For the set of functions $f : X\to X$, for some set X, the equation $f x = g$ ($x$ is an unknown function, not a variable) has solution if and only if $\mathrm{Im}(g) \subseteq \mathrm{Im}(f)$
4. For $\mathbb{R}[X]$, the equation $p * x = q$ has solution if only if $q$ is divisible by $p$.

Are there any generalizations of this statements?

Some common things I have found  in all these cases is that we are working with a monoid $M$, we have a  "rank" function $r : M \to Y$, for some set $Y$ such that ( $r(ab) \le \min(r(a),r(b))$), where $\le$ is a partial ordering of $Y$.

P.S: More specifically, we have for our examples:

1. The rank function is the image of the linear map associated with the matrix, the partial ordering is the inclusion order.
2. The rank function is $r : \mathbb{Z_m} \to \mathbb{Z}$,  $ r(a) = \gcd(a,m)$ and the partial ordering is the divisibility ($\mid$) relation
3. The rank function is $Im(f)$ and the partial ordering is the inclusion relation
4. The rank function is the $r : \mathbb{R}[X] \to \mathcal{P}(R[X]),  r(x) = \langle p\rangle$ (elements of the ideal generated by $p$)  and the partial ordering is the inclusion relation.

Answer (score 3):

Your first example is not correct.

Rank$(B)$ is less than rank $(A)$ for
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0 \\0&1&0\\0&1&0\\\end{pmatrix}X=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0 \\0&0&0\\0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}$$

but the equation cannot be solved.

You can however say "only if".